# How to implement a client to server connection that is secure and syncs

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, pouchdb

I’m struggling to understand how the pouchDB interactions should be implemented. Say I want an offline-first app with syncing and auth, would I need to implement a middleman such as a node server to ensure my credentials to my main server are protected as having a PouchDB on the client with new PouchDB(‘name’, ‘https://username:password@server/dbname’) my creds to my main database are exposed. Would it be better to connect to a node server and that decide wether or not to allow access?

### [image]

How would this be done? Can I handle a direct connection to the server with auth and it be secure? Or is a middle man needed to ensure security.

If a middle man is needed will you need to implement a sort of api i.e

```
//client
const db = new Pouch('days')
db.sync(remote)

//server
app.get('/db/days', (res, req) => // do some pouch stuff for each db)
```

> https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhat simplified, if your application is backed by an application 'master' database and it runs using a single set of credentials, you need a middle layer: you will then need to multiplex all users' data into a single database.

Applications backed by CouchDB/Cloudant often instead use the 'database-per-user' pattern, meaning that each application user have their own database, and their own credentials, meaning that a lot of things become simpler, conceptually, and a middle layer might not be required.

Note that the 'database-per-user' pattern needs some thought to scale well if you intend to cater for millions of users.

On Cloudant you can also use API keys to define access.

If you want the simplicity of the db-per-user pattern without (some of) the drawbacks, you may be able to draw some inspiration from Cloudant Envoy (https://github.com/cloudant-labs/envoy) -- a thin proxy that multiplexes users' data into a single db, whilst still presenting the db-per-user API surface outwards. Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of Envoy.

Comment: so i can get this straight in my head so you have a client that connects to a server using lets say using pouchDB that server then proxies the real couchDB using some form of proxy that example you gave looks like it sets up some basic crud actions for the database or will api handlers have to be created to pass to the couchDB server

Comment: Envoy is a *replication* proxy. You can point PouchDB at it and it will think that the remote end is a normal Cloudant/CouchDB instance. See e.g. https://medium.com/offline-camp/scaling-offline-first-with-envoy-ada42d130cfc -- this helps scaling the "database per user" model a bit.

Comment: Where can I read about the challenges of scaling database-per-user to millions of users?

Comment: Possibly a bit off-topic for this conversation, but if you create another question I'll furnish you with a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that I use depends on crypto-pouch (https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/crypto-pouch) to encrypt all of your databases on the client. The first time the site is visited, username/password is required to access a cloud couch instance and get things installed on the client.

During this process, a pouchdb database is created on the client for each possible user (retrieved from the cloud couch instance), with each database encrypted with the user's password, and in each database is placed a single document that contains a master password. In addition to these user databases, the 'main' database that stores real data is created and encrypted with the master password.

Subsequent visits to the site whether online or offline, will require the user to enter their username/password, which will attempt to unlock the appropriate user database and get the master password, which is then used to unlock the main database. Only with the master password can the data be accessed and a sync performed to the cloud instance.